# How to debug Iowait hight (%wa in top) on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm getting a high Iowait error on an AWS EC2 instance. I have installed MongoDB version 3.0.15 and telegraf on this Server.
Recently, Iowait on the Server will sometimes increase above 10% for a few minutes, without any rules. During high Iowait insert and update operations on MongoDB become very slow (about 20 -> 40s, normally 0s)

My Server Specs:

CPU:
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 4

RAM:
Use/Total: 22.2/30.6 GiB

Disk
Use/Total: 872/1070 GiB

CPU statistic in day

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uljlI.png)

What caused this error? How can I fix it?